# Bash open Firefox Window, then each subsequent window in tabs

Tags: firefox, bash

I know as long as Firefox has the "New pages should be opened in - a new tab" selected, the following code will open specified urls in new tabs to the firefox window last selected.

```
firefox '<url here>'
```

Works great.  However with many tabs to open the user needs to leave computer as until all open as desired.

Is it possible to (in bash):

A) Launch a new Firefox window, open all subsequent pages in tabs in that window
and
B) Let the user interact with other open firefox windows while the remaining tabs continue to load in the newly launched firefox window?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think the following addresses part (A) of your requirements:

```
firefox google.com &
firefox -new-tab yahoo.com &
firefox -new-tab bing.com &
```

Regarding (B), if it is acceptable to ingore the user's existing profile settings, perhaps load something else with the `-P` option:

```
firefox -no-remote -P “<path-to-other-profile>” google.com &
```

Answer (score 0):

this works fine for me:

```
firefox http://google.com/ http://yahoo.com/
```

Comment: yea that will open a new window and a tab, but i'm needing to pause 5 seconds between the tabs so I need it to add the tabs one at a time.

Which this would still technically work, I'm just hoping to be able to let it happen in the background.